# Test between describe '...' do ... end does not take into account the test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I have a test that looks like this:

```
class PageTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  describe "test" do
    test "should not save without attributes" do
      page = Page.new
      assert !page.save
    end
  end

end
```

When running the tests, I get `0 tests, 0 assertions`.  If I remove the describe "test" do, I get the `1 test, 1 assertions`. So I have the feeling that the describe "..." do is actually making the test disappear.

What is going on here? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're mixing up minitest `specs` and `ActiveSupport::TestCase`. If you check the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#unit-testing-your-models) on testing the `test` method is explained but it's not used with `describe`.

> Rails adds a test method that takes a test name and a block. It
>   generates a normal MiniTest::Unit test with method names prefixed with
>   test_. So,

```
test "the truth" do
  assert true
end
```

> acts as if you had written

```
def test_the_truth
  assert true
end
```

The `describe` syntax is explained in the [minitest docs](http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/) under the `spec` section  and is used with `it` (and not `test`). Like so:

```
 describe "when asked about cheeseburgers" do
   it "must respond positively" do
     @meme.i_can_has_cheezburger?.must_equal "OHAI!"
   end
 end
```